# Why It keeps saying that passwords aren't matching?

Tags: ios, swift

It keeps show me the alert "Passwords don't match", I can't see where is the problem. 
And if I delete the code that matches the passwords it crashes.
I know for sure that the IBOutlets and IBAction are properly connected.

```
@IBAction func signupButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let userEmail = email
        let userPassword = password
        let userRepeatPassword = repeatPassword



        // Check empty fields
        if (email.hasText == false) || (password.hasText == false) || (repeatPassword.hasText == false) {
            alertMessage(userMessage: "All fields are required!")
            return
        }

        // Check if passwords match
        if repeatPassword != password {
            alertMessage(userMessage: "Passwords do not match!")
            return
        }


        // Store data
        UserDefaults.standard.set(userEmail, forKey: "userEmail")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(userPassword, forKey: "userPassword")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        // Display alert message with confirmation
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Signed up!", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { action in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            alert.addAction(okAction)

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func alertMessage (userMessage: String) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(okAction)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect these lines are wrong:

```
    let userEmail = email
    let userPassword = password
    let userRepeatPassword = repeatPassword
```

Given your other code, I suspect `email` and the others are UITextFields, not Strings. I suspect you meant this:

```
    let userEmail = email.text ?? ""
    let userPassword = password.text ?? ""
    let userRepeatPassword = repeatPassword.text ?? ""
```